# Uploading an image to a Canvas using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm new to JS, but I'm currently trying to upload an image to an HTML canvas. There isn't a problem with the code, I just keep getting an error in the console that says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).
In my IDE, it says that the image is there, but for some reason it's not showing on the preview. Any help would be appreciated!`

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas1');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
//console.log(canvas);

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

load_image();

var base_image;

function load_image() {
  "use strict";
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = '\Images\trial.jpg';

  base_image.onload = function() {
    c.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
  };
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.canvas1 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 98.7vw;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sylvanas</title>

  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <canvas class="canvas1">
 </canvas>
  <!--<canvas class="canvas2">
 </canvas>-->

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

`

Comment: Where do the backslashes come from to the image URL? You're  actually trying to read the image from `ImagesTABrial.jpg`.

Comment: @Teemu see my answer its actually convertd to ` Images rial.jpg`

Comment: @AbhishekMathur `\t` is TABULATOR character. And why to make a simple task complex? Just write the url using slashes as everybody else are doing ... most likely even you in your own code.

Comment: @Teemu yes you're right

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the wrong path, [\] in javascript escapes the next letter

```js
console.log('\Images\trial.jpg')
```

so when you put path as "'\Images\trial.jpg'" it results in `Images rial.jpg`

You can either escape the path,use String.raw`this my \n really raw path` or simply put the path in backticks [`like this`]